# Definition of structure group associated with fiber bundle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I was studying fiber bundle from Spanier book.In that book there is a definition of structure group associated with a fiber bundle.But I am not able to understand the definition properly.Could somebody give me the definition little bit elaborately or another version of the definition
?I will be thankful if somebody give me other reference for that definition.

Comment: What's the definition given by Spanier?

Comment: A elementary definition would be: A fiber bundle has structure group $G\subseteq Homoe(X)$ iff one can choose a trivializing covering such that all transition functions have values in $G$.

Comment: @archipelago could you give me an example where the structure group does not exist?

Comment: The "structure group" does always exist, since you can choose $G=Homeo(X)$ in any case. A good example to have in mind is the following: If you start with a $n$-dimensional real vector bundle and take the associated frame bundle, the structure group will be $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. A vector bundle has structure group $GL^+_n(\mathbb{R})$ iff it admits an orientation, where I denote by $GL^+_n(\mathbb{R})$ the subgroup of matrices with positive determinant.